# Is std::exchange specialized for atomics?

Tags: c++

`std::exchange(x,y)` assigns `x` the value `y` and returns the old value of `x`.

Is this function specialized for atomic values, i.e. will it use `std::atomic_exchange`?
I am thinking the answer is no, in that case why not? Was it ever considered? Seems like a good idea to me.

I am using this for resetting a simple counter and was just wondering whether if I make the counter atomic sometime in the future to support threading, whether it will just work or be unsafe.

How can I write generic function where it will use atomic exchange for atomic types and ordinary exchange for ordinary types?

Comment: `std::exchange` has no overloads. And if you want one, you just create an overload having `std::atomic` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write generic function where it will use atomic exchange for
> atomic types and ordinary exchange for ordinary types?

You can detect whether `obj.exchange(x)` is a valid expression (which works for `std::atomic`) to determine whether to use member function `exchange` or free function `std::exchange`.

```
#include <utility>
 
template<class T, class U = T>
constexpr
T my_exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value) {
  if constexpr (requires { obj.exchange(std::forward<U>(new_value)); })
    return obj.exchange(std::forward<U>(new_value));
  else
    return std::exchange(obj, std::forward<U>(new_value));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zYKrMP8Pj)